# Installing PHP from binaries download on Windows XP

Tags: php, iis, installation, windows-xp

After downloading and extracting "php-5.4.3-Win32-VC9-x86.zip" on Windows XP, I tried running each of these files (one at a time), and they all bring up a Windows dialog and do nothing.

```
php.exe
php-win.exe
php-cgi.exe
```

Am I installing PHP incorrectly by running these files?

=========================

## update: 5/8/2012 @ 4:03pm

**Best tutorial I've found yet.  Although I'm still getting the error below.**

http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-php-5-on-iis-with-fastcgi.html

=========================

**Error when navigating to page:**

*CGI Error ... The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:*

Resolution seems to involve adding this code, but I'm trying to figure out where.

```
print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n\n";
```

... I placed this code in the top of my PHP file, and the error went away.

**This is also a very good tutorial, but doesn't use FastCGI.**

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/installing_php_5_iis_5_simple_steps

===========

***Now my page is blank, but it must be with the Kimai index.php page, because I got the Hello World application to work fine.***

Comment: Do you have a web server installed? Otherwise, you're running it through the CLI (Command Line Interface). If that's what you want be sure to run php.exe <path>\file.php

Comment: php.exe expects to be given a script to run (e.g. `php.exe somescript.php`), or be told to go into PHP shell mode (e.g. `php.exe -a`), otherwise it'll just exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's primary method of use is through a module to Apache (or any other webserver including IIS, nginx and many others) either in the form of a direct module or through CGI. You can also run php scripts through the command line. Executing the php.exe file directly will not produce any results.

Simple installation instructions for Apache:

go to apachelounge.com

go to the downloads page

download the first thing (httpd-2.4.2-win32.zip)

unzip this to C:\Apache24

download php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.4-win32.zip from that same site

unzip php5apache2_4.dll into your php directory (assumed to be C:\php from here on out)

add the following lines of code to the end of C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

then run cmd as administrator type the following:

```
cd c:\Apache24\bin
httpd.exe -k install
```

then run apache monitor (found in that same C:\Apache24\bin folder) and click start apache

now from your browser navigate to localhost, this will display a greeting message, placing php files in C:\Apache24\htdocs will allow you to access them via your browser.

Comment: I'm planning on running PHP on IIS

Comment: I have not personally installed PHP on IIS, but from what I can tell it should be a simple process with PHP Manager for IIS (http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/)

Comment: see my update ... I wasn't aware the install was specific to a web server.  Haven't found one forum with adequate instructions that work yet.

Comment: you could try this: http://forums.iis.net/t/1047300.aspx and take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php
it looks like all you need to do in IIS if you have already downloaded PHP is create the mappings so that IIS knows how to handle .php files. Also, PHP Manager for IIS should let you do this via a GUI in IIS.

Comment: +1 ... good info! In your answer, not your last comment. :-) There was a lot of jibber jabber in those last couple links.

Answer (score 1):

Those executables are for the web server. By executing those, you are calling up the PHP interpreter that handles PHP processing. You need to find a package that automates the install process.

As per tutorials, these might help (not sure, I've only installed PHP on IIS once, and that was years ago).

- [PHP for IIS](http://php.iis.net/)
- [How to Install PHP on IIS](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx)
- [Best of All...](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis.php)

Comment: Unfortunately that Web Installer is not available on Windows XP.  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/604/troubleshooting-problems-with-microsoft-web-platform-installer/ ... I'll post what I've tried in my question